# Visual Studio 2015 not creating subfolders for projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I try to create a new project by selecting visual c++/general/empty project. The subfolders for the project are not created. It was working just fine for one project then I deleted that project and haven't been able to get it to create them since. The folders I'm talking about are like the source folder and others when you open up the project folder. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project, it exists inside a "virtual" solution. The solution becomes visible once you add a second project. Go in the File menu, Add, New Project.

Comment: In the class view there is still nothing.

Comment: Well, did you add a class? You CHOSE to create an empty project, why? You could have used one of the standard application templates instead.

Comment: I did this to create an Assembly project. On the video I was using to learn to use visual studio this is what they had done. When I did it for the first time it work just as in the video. However my computer did a restart and the I lost the project for not saving it. Then when I followed the instructions again the subfolder such as the source folder isn't being created. here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyBnsmwe8Og

Comment: I just tried to do a console application and the same is for it, visual studio doesn't create the subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after several hours trying to figure out what had happened. I finally came to the conclusion that it had something to do with the solution explore. When I was looking for it I had opened it up to view it. Turns out that what I was looking before was the class view, and when I opened the solution explore the folders I was looking for were right were they should have been.